# How do I include a ScriptBundle in a user control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-optimization

I have some legacy ASP.NET WebForms code that uses RegisterClientScriptInclude in a class that inherits from UserControl.  I want to replace the multiple calls to RegisterClientScriptInclude with a single new-fangled [Bundle](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).  How do I resolve a bundle URL from my bundle route, deep inside a compiled assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've registered the bundle already and just want to generate a reference to the bundle.

The simplist way is to just call

```
BundleCollection.ResolveBundleUrl(<path to bundle, i.e. "~/bundles/mybundle">).
```

Note by not using the Scripts helper to render out the tags, you will always get a reference to the bundle, there won't be the automatic non bundle functionality when you call the ResolveBundleUrl directly.

Comment: "Automatic non-bundle functionality"?

Comment: Meaning bundling and minification is off in debug mode when using the Scripts/Styles helpers

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
private void RegisterJavaScriptBundle(string bundleIdent)
    {
        var bundleUrl = String.Format("~/bundles/{0}", bundleIdent);

        var name = String.Format("Bundle{0}", bundleIdent);

        if (ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.GetDefinition(name) == null)
            ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition(name, new ScriptResourceDefinition { Path = bundleUrl });

        ScriptManager.RegisterNamedClientScriptResource(this.Page, name);
    }
```

Than call it in the load event of the usercontrol:

```
this.RegisterJavaScriptBundle("MyBundle");
```

This will generate reference to the script with the content hash:

```
<script src="/bundles/MyBundle?v=B6mdgLTYJ2gPQv_XxE07ACAAaNA6Lo4L_KxViWZE-CY1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```